# Difference between two independent geometric random variables

Tags: probability, convolution

Let $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ be independent random variables:
$\xi_1 \simeq Geom(1/2), \xi_2 \simeq Geom(1/6)$.

How do you find the probability mass function of $\eta=\xi_1-\xi_2$ using convolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(\xi_1 - \xi_2 = k) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(\xi_2 = i,\xi_1 = k+i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(\xi_1=i)P(\xi_2 = k+i),$$ and you can calculate this sum easily using the mass functions of $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$.

Comment: Why $\xi_2=k+i$? Shouldn't it be $\xi_2=i-k$?

Comment: If $\xi_2 = i$ and you want $\xi_1 - \xi_2 = k$,... then... adding $\xi_2$ to both sides of the second equation gives...: $\xi_1 = k+i$.

Comment: There is another explanation also given at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554878/subtraction-between-two-independent-geometric-random-variables?rq=1