# Using convolution with two independent geometric random variables

Tags: probability, convolution

Consider two independent geometric random variables $$X\sim \text{Geometric}(1/2)  \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \  Y\sim \text{Geometric}(3/4).$$
My goal is to find 
$$\mathbb{P}(X-Y=2).$$
Using the convolution formula 
$$\mathbb{P}(X-Y=k)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X=i)\mathbb{P}(Y=i+k),$$
I obtained the sum 
$$\mathbb{P}(X-Y=2)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{i-1}\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{i+1}.$$
This simplifies to the sum 
$$\frac{3}{16}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{i}\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{i}.$$
This is a geometric sum which converges to 
$$\frac{\frac{3}{128}}{1-\frac{1}{8}}=\boxed{\frac{3}{112}}.$$
However, I am not too confident about this answer.  For example, one of my friends was doing this problem and he used the formula 
$$\mathbb{P}(X-Y=k)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X=i+k)\mathbb{P}(Y=i),$$
leading to a different answer.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Note: $\mathsf P(X-Y=k) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathsf P(X=i+k)\mathsf P(Y=i)$ because you need $X=Y+k$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Why? Everywhere I look I am seeing otherwise.

Comment: If $Y>X$ then $X-Y<0$. @StatGuy

Comment: @GrahamKemp In this problem $X>Y.$

Comment: @StateGuy  Exactly.  So you need to sum the product of probabilities of the events $\{Y=i\}$ and $\{X=i+k\}$.

Comment: You found the solution to $\mathsf P(\underset{\uparrow}{Y-X}=k) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathsf P(X=i)\mathsf P(Y=i+k)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734216/difference-between-two-independent-geometric-random-variables     Is this wrong then?  I think there is a notation error in the last term.

Comment: Yes, the indices were switched for no apparent reason.  Possibly a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considered a random variable geometric as the number of trials until the first success: $$Z\sim Geo(p)$$
if $$\mathbb{P}(Z=z)={(1-p)}^zp,\quad z=1,2,3,\dots$$
where $0\le p\le 1$ is the probability of success.

Note that
$$ \{X-Y=k\}=\bigcup_{i=k+1}^\infty\{Y=i-k,X=i\}=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty\{X=j+k,Y=j\}.$$
Then 
$$ \mathbb{P}(X-Y=k)=\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y=i-k,X=i)=\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y=i-k)\mathbb{P}(X=i)$$
and 
$$\mathbb{P}(X-Y=k)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X=j+k)\mathbb{P}(Y=j).$$

Comment: Thank you!  Quick question- what if you have $\mathbb{P}(aX-bY=k)$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}?$

Comment: A similar formula is obtained, because $aX$ and $bY$ are also independent.